# How to refresh a Datagrid automatically if I'm using a List to collect information from Database?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms-designer

I'm doing like a Mcdonalds' control panel to choose 
what clients want to take. I'm doing it with Windows Forms
using C#. What I made was creating a class called products
and after in Form1.cs I made a List where I'll put the
products read from database.
I managed to do this and show the results on a DataGrid.
My problem is that when I make the selection of the products
and then I click on the button Send, the Datagrid doesn't refresh automatically. I have to close the program and when
i restart it i can see the changes.

My question is, does anyone know how to update de Datagrid
whitout restarting the program?

Thanks very much, I add my code below:

![]My_windows_form[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBshM.jpg)

#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();       
        String connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1; Database=mydatabase; Uid=root; Pwd=;";    
        List<products> listproducts = new List<products>();

        public string product;
        public string quantity;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            startConn(); 
        }
        private void startConn()
        {
            try
            {   
                conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                conn.Open();                
                textBox3.Text= "Correct connection";
                //we call the function READ
                read();
            }
            catch (MySqlException)
            {
               textBox3.Text="An error has ocurred";
            }
        }       
       public void read()
        { 
            MySqlCommand instruccio = conn.CreateCommand();
            instruccio.CommandText = "Select * from products";
            MySqlDataReader search = instruccio.ExecuteReader();
            while (search.Read())
            {
                products prod = new products();
                prod.IdProd = search["idProd"].ToString();                    
                prod.Name = search["nomProd"].ToString();
                prod.Quantity = Int32.Parse(search["quantitat"].ToString());
                listproducts.Add(prod);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = listproducts;

            search.Close();
            search.Dispose();

        }    
        private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Button Send (Enviar in spanish)
        {
           try
            {           
                //before updating the stock in database we query the total quantity of the product selected
                MySqlCommand instruccio1 = connexio.CreateCommand();              
                instruccio1.CommandText = "Select quantitat from productes where `nomProd`='"+ this.product +"'";               
                MySqlDataReader read = instruccio1.ExecuteReader();               
                int result = 0;               
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    resultat=Int32.Parse(read["quantitat"].ToString());                       
                }
                read.Dispose();
                instruccio1.Dispose();

                if (this.quantity != 0)
                {                   
                    if (result > this.quantity)
                    {

                    int difference = result - this.quantity;
                    MySqlCommand instruccio2 = conn.CreateCommand();
                    instruccio2.CommandText = "UPDATE products set `quantitat`='" + this.difference + "' where products.nomProd='" + this.product + "'";
                    instruccio2.ExecuteNonQuery();                                
                    conn.Close();
                                    startConn();
                    textBox1.Text= "";
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    this.quantity = "";
                    this.product = "";                              
                }
                else 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There's no quantity.");                
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception xe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("",xe.Message);
            }         
        }
        private void btnEsborrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Erase button
        {
            this.quantity = "";
            this.product = "";
            this.aEnviar = 0;
            textBox1.Text = quantity;
            textBox2.Text = product;
        }

....
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is the following:

1. Add a timer control on your form and set the time you want its Tick event to be fired, it is put in the Interval property in milliseconds.
2. on this event call your function `startConn`.

and thats it, very easy :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried what you said but did not work. On the other hand I tried to close the connection and to call the function startConn just after making the update but not worked. I don't know what's happening :(

Comment: try to add this line: "List<products> listproducts = new List<products>();" inside your read() method.

Comment: Thanks very very much. Was exactly this!!I hadn't thought on that. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score -1):

In your `read()` method before

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = listproducts;
```

add

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

Then call your `startConn()` method whenever you want.

Comment: how can this help him updating the grid automatically??

Comment: This first of all will help him to get the updated list without having to create new and new instances of the list as you added in your answer. If you read carefully in his question this what he can't really achieve. And if you read my answer carefully I just told him to call his startConn() whenever he wants which might be the event you show to him. Now do I graduate with this comment teacher???

Comment: Oh by the way he don't even have to call startConn() anywhere else since he already call this method after his update. So his problem was clearly that he couldn't see the changes in his datagrid.

Comment: first of all sorry if you felt offended :), what i mean my friend is that he need to update it automatically so the timer will be a good solution on the other hand about the connection i would prefer do as i told him in the comments in my answer to declare the products list in the read method.

Comment: calling the startConn() from the timer will help him to update the grid without physically clicking an event. edit your answer by anyway so that i remove the -1 as well :)

Comment: @Ali Yes I felt offended because clearly you didn't read well his question including his code (starConn() is called after his update), and you didn't read also well my answer. But still you did find time to comment me and maybe negativily vote me... Anyhow not bad feelings.

Comment: @Ali As I said your solution is fine, but this was not really his problem. I am not going to edit anything on my answer. You can keep your negative vote there. I am here to help people if I can and not to be the master of votes.